# Container div height relativo ao tamanho da pagina?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

Como deixar a altura(height) da div Container do bootstrap relativo ao dimensionamento da pagina?

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">
      its works!
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Boa noite Erick, tudo bem?

Cara não sei se entendi muito bem sua pergunta, porem eu acredito que a solução para seu problema é colocar no css na div container "height:100vh;